# When submitting more than 200 menus, I get "Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Tags: menus

I have a site with a large number of nested menus.

I solved the problem after following the solution proposed here

[Menu limit, cannot add new menu items](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75934/menu-limit-cannot-add-new-menu-items?rq=1)

and including max_input_vars setting.

For some time this worked but now when I attempt to save menus I get

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

and the logs report nothing.

I try to increase to max_input_vars setting to 20000 but to no avail.

Any help would be invaluable.

Thank you.

Comment: I am sure it is the "capacity problems" part that is relevant. You are getting timeout or memory exhaustion or a database crash. Something like that. You will probably need to talk to your host, but 200 menus is a huge number

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The error message appears when Uploading 100% is reached and presumably the whole menu structure is loaded on the server. Do you think more memory would help?

Comment: Memory might help but I'd guess you have an architecture problem.