# I can't add more pages to menu - menu delete pages

Tags: menus, pages, customization

Two days ago I decided to add three more pages to the menu on [my site](http://tornaia.com). I already had like 140 pages in the menu, so this is something I know how to do. But I hadn't done it in some months, so maybe something has changed.

Anyway, when I pressed "save menu", two thing happened.

- All pages after page number 89 (yes, I have counted) got deleted from the menu. In fact, on [my site](http://tornaia.com) you can see that the right part of my menu is all empty.
- The menu was no longer the primary menu, so I had to go back in and save it as primary menu again.

So now I have a menu with only 89 pages. If I add a page number 90, it disappears when I press save menu. And besides I will have to go in and save the menu as primary menu again. If I add a page called A as page number 90, and then switch place with another page called B (so the page B now is number 90), then it's the page B that disappears when I press save menu. So all pages after page 89 gets deleted from the menu when I press save menu. That's a bit frustrating. Why is this happening? What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menu limit, cannot add new menu items](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75934/menu-limit-cannot-add-new-menu-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely explanation is that you've hit a PHP limit here - namely max_input_vars.

A more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792891/wordpress-removes-my-menu-items-if-above-the-limit-of-90-menu-items).

The solution is not inside WordPress I'm afraid, you're gonna have to venture into your site's PHP settings.

Or, of course, reorganize your menus into something more manageable.

Comment: That worked! I contacted my host, and they made a php.ini file that I can change myself. Then I put `max_input_vars = 3000` in that file, and now I can have more pages :)

So thanks again, this was very helpful! :)